# SVG into coumpoundDrawable doesn't look centered to text

Tags: android, text, layout, center, drawable

I have this layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/account_display_name"
      style="@style/AccountDataDisplayName"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:gravity="center_vertical"
      tools:text="DisplayNameIsLongSoItShouldBeTruncatedAtSomePoint"/>
  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/account_name"
      style="@style/AccountDataAccountName"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      tools:text="emailisverylongaswellwewantittogettruncated@gmail.longdomain.com"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

when the visibility of `account_display_name` is toggelled GONE and VISIBLE dynamically.

In one case only accountName is visible
Then the coumpoundDrawable icon seems too hight.

[image]

In other case both accountName and DisplayName are visible.
Then the coumpoundDrawable icon seems too low.

[image]

*I will add layout ispector image soon.

this is the java code:

```
   TextViewCompat.setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(
        targetTextView, null, null, drawable, null);
```

how can it be that `"setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds"` makes different centering with the same resource?

I guess it's because the accountName is `wrap_content` so it's bigger when alone?

what logic of centering and positionning cause this difference? maybe I'm missing something in the compundDrawable positionning.

Or how should I fix this?

`layout_gravitig:"center_vertical"` in the xml for `accountName` and `DisplayName`?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
TextView textViewCompat= convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewCompat);
textViewCompat.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.ic_your_svg, 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: according to the android doc, it's the same. why do you think it's different

Comment: Ok haha! Just get your response at the android documentation. (:

Comment: not sure i understand you. why do you think it's different  ?

Answer (score 0):

Normally the compound drawable gravity is center, you need to check your SVG viewport bounds to see if they position the vector in the center or there's a bit of top padding above your vector.

Comment: but even if there is top padding- why would it sometimes be too high? i mean there is inconcistency

Comment: In the picture you provided the drawable doesn't seem too high to me, compared to the text.

Comment: but why isn't it the same centering when dealing with the 2nd image?